# wait() sub causing beep

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am getting a beep in my sub when executing a wait timer.  The beep occurs on doevents and seemingly only happens the first time the sub is called (so on the first wait).  It sounds like a messagebox popup beep. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
Private Sub wait(ByVal interval As Integer)

    Dim stopW As New Stopwatch
    stopW.Start()
    Do While stopW.ElapsedMilliseconds < interval
        ' Allows your UI to remain responsive and apparently is causing beeping
        My.Application.DoEvents() ' I get a beep when this line is executed
    Loop
    stopW.Stop()
End Sub
```

Comment: This code will drive your CPU to 100%. Please don't wait that way.

Comment: @usr:I like your comment, but it would be better if you had provided a recommended way to wait.

Comment: He could stick a Thread.Sleep(50) in the loop, which is better than just spinning in a tight loop, but still not a good solution. Better would be using a System.Timer, but it begs the question, why does he need to have a wait on the UI thread in the first place?

Comment: @hatchet I am using this because I am pulling elements from a database, and often times, the web browser control has finished loading, but i am waiting on elements to populate. I thought about testing the existence of the item on the page, but the item will exist, it just wont hold data at that point yet, thus, the reason I have been using wait() after browser readystate = 4.  I was advised against using thread.sleep because it pauses the entire application, where, I just want to wait for elements to finish pulling from a DB

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` does not pause the entire application, just the current thread. It is used because it signals to the OS that you are not currently doing anything.

Comment: @Kratz But I am, I am waiting for the elements to fully load into the textboxes.  Or am I completely misunderstanding, and that even if I sleep the application for so long, the data should load into the frame